# HTML form split to two different submissions

Tags: javascript, html, shopping-cart, payment-processing

I performed a shopping cart integrated to my website and now I am trying to use only one form to be filled by customer (personal information) but I am facing a issue because I would like to use two different submit button depending on the payment platform chosen by customer. Does anybody know a simple solution for that? I appreciate in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

you have to pass name attribute with different value of name attribute in button tags like that --

```
<button type="submit" name="button1">Button 1</button>

<button type="submit" name="button2">Button 2</button>
```

In php code --

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['button1]))
{
// here we will add code of button 1
}

if(isset($_POST['button2]))
{
// here we will add code of button 2
}

?>
```

please try this .....

Answer (score 0):

Use multi step form pattern.You can find huge of examples by searching on google.